# Why is my SIGNAL not working in Django - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

first of all, I'm not a developer.

Trying to build an Application with Django (Version 3.1.2) but facing some issues with signals.

I have this Models in my `models.py`:

```
class PhoneNumbers(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(_('Category'), max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

and a Model `Persons`

```
class Persons(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    number = models.CharField(_(Number), max_length=255)
    ...
```

The code in my `signals.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import PhoneNumbers, Persons

@receiver(post_save, sender=Persons)
def save_contract(instance, sender, created, **kwargs):
    print("Request finished!")
```

When I save a Person I expect to get a PRINT in the console output, but get nothing. What is wrong?

I also add in `__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

My apps.py looks like:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not load the signals module. You can do this in the `MyAppConfig`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        import apps.signals  # noqa
```

Comment: Hi @Willem Van Onsem,
thank you for the code, but still not working. Should I install any module manually? 

`import apps.signals  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps'`

`import signals  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'signals'`

Comment: @sokolata: where did you save the `signals.py` file? This should be in the directory of your app. If the app has a different name, then of course you import `import my_app_name.signals`, so it should be the `signals` module of the app where you defined the signals.